# Performance of C++ STL containers. Better speed in struct or without struct?

Tags: c++, performance, struct, stl, containers

I have some container for data and think about to put them into a struct (easier to give it to functions etc).
The program should be as fast as possible. Are the accesses to containers in structs slower or exactly the same?

```
// data without struct
double d1;
bool b1;
std::map<std::string, std::deque<double>> map1;
std::vector<std::deque<int>> a1;
std::vector<std::deque<int>> a2;
std::vector<std::vector<<std::deque<int>>> a3;
std::vector<std::vector<<std::deque<int>>> a4;
// ... and perhaps even more
```

**VS**

```
struct containerstruct
{
   double d1;
   bool b1;
   std::map<std::string, std::deque<double>> map1;
   std::vector<std::deque<int>> a1;
   std::vector<std::deque<int>> a2;
   std::vector<std::vector<<std::deque<int>>> a3;
   std::vector<std::vector<<std::deque<int>>> a4;
   // ... and perhaps even more
};
containerstruct data;
```

Comment: Well, did you measure? Premature optimization is the root of all evil :)

Comment: There will be no difference. But why don't you try it out yourself?

Comment: It depends on how you use it all. And don't care about premature optimization now, first of all make sure you have a nice program that is readable, maintainable and works. Then if the performance isn't up to the requirements you measure and benchmark and profile to find the bottlenecks, and concentrate on the top few of those.

Comment: In order to answer what will be faster on your machine with your compiler on your data, I need your compiler, your machine, your data, and $400/hour.

Comment: You almost certainly want to put some naming around those containers, even if it is a set of `typedef std::vector<std::deque<int>> DomainRelevantName`, but more preferably wrap them in separate classes that enforce useful invariants

Answer (score 2):

This is just another one of those "will my program run faster if I use global variables?" questions. Fortunately, unlike the situation some 20+ years ago, the answer is now a resounding ***no***!

With modern, optimizing compilers, the resulting code will be nearly identical. At *worst*, you'll have one pointer dereference to access a field, which will not make a detectable difference in performance.

Therefore, you should write the code that is readable and maintainable, which means encapsulating related things together. This is, by the way, the whole premise of object-oriented design.

Comment: I think you can not compare this. global variables are a question of scope and not about encapsulation.

The question referred to performance. Object-oriented design is not the first choice for time-critical applications :-) and a struct is a precursor of object-oriented design therefore the question.

Comment: I answered the performance question. You haven't made a compelling argument why either encapsulation or scope would affect performance. The compiler doesn't know, either.